# Is it possible to exclude a pipeline in datafactory using yaml script in AZ DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-data-factory, pipeline

I have three datafactories across the environments under my subscription. And all the datafactories are in sync with the same code. I am trying to test my preprod datafactory. I have a preprod yml file and I have two pipelines in my datafactory. I am trying to exclude one pipeline from my preprod datafactory. Is it possible to exclude a pipeline in my preprod datafactory.

I have tried using the following code to exclude a pipeline from my yml script.

```yaml
steps:
- task: AzurePowerShell@5
  displayName: Deploy ADF
  inputs: 
    azureSubscription: ******
    ScriptType: InlineScript
    Inline: 
      'New-AzResourceGroupDeployment 
      -ResourceGroupName "******"
      -TemplateParameterFile "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Preproduction/ARMTemplateParametersForFactory-Preprod.json"/ !*. -pipeline.POC test pipeline
      -TemplateFile "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/******/ARMTemplateForFactory.json"
      -factoryName "*******" -Mode "Incremental"'
    azurePowerShellVersion: LatestVersion
```

Answer (score 0):

The ARM templates support to conditionally deploy resources that have defined in the template json files.

You need to update the template json files by adding the conditions to conditionally deploy the resources based on the value of a parameter.

For more details, you can see "[**Conditional deployment in ARM templates**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/conditional-resource-deployment)".

---

To run the ARM templates deployment in a pipeline on DevOps DevOps, you also can use the [**AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/azure-resource-manager-template-deployment-v3?view=azure-pipelines) task.

---